# Is there a way to fail a Linux kernel build if prompted for config settings?

Tags: linux-kernel

When building the Linux kernel, if the current `.config` is missing settings, the build is interrupted to prompt the user to configure them. This is fine for manual building, but presents a problem for automated tests. Is there a way to fail the build in this case? If not, is there a way to check for these conditions ahead of time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach to take probably differs depending on the kernel version, so you will need to check beforehand, but here are some options.

The `oldconfig` Makefile target is the one responsible for updating `.config` prompting for all the options that are missing. It will list and describe the needed options asking for input from standard input. If nothing is missing, it will just output something like `No change to .config`. The output probably varies slightly across different kernel versions. You could run `make oldconfig </dev/null` and check the output. Note that when standard input cannot be read this updates `.config` with default values, if I recall correctly. Just try and check for yourself.

Using sh/bash you could do something like this:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
#
# Build kernel, but fail in case .config needs update.
#

cp .config .config.bak
make -j oldconfig </dev/null 2>/dev/null | grep -iF 'No change to .config'

if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # Restore backup config since oldconfig changed it
    mv -f .config.bak .config

    # Fail build
    echo '.config needs to be updated' >&2
    exit 1
fi

rm -f .config.bak

# Continue build
make -j
```

There is also a `listnewconfig` target that simply lists options that need to be set/changed before building. The output will be different in case of no missing options: in the latest kernel it outputs nothing, on older kernels it just outputs one line telling you which command is being run to check. So again you could check the output of this target, using a shell script similar to the one above.

Additionally, from Linux v3.7 onwards, an `olddefconfig` target has been added: this target does the same job as `oldconfig`, but takes no input and sets all the needed missing options to their default value automatically.